# Value of people field does not show up on result of rest api

Tags: rest

I have two lists, **Notification1** and **Notification2**, and they have the one people field named **Owner**. The first one is created via SOM, and the last one is created via SharePoint UI. The problem with the **Notification1** is that its value does not show up on rest api result.

Normally, the result would look like that as shown on the **Notification2** list; however, it does not on **Notification1** list.

```
<d:OwnerId m:type="Edm.Int32">7</d:OwnerId>
```

If result like so, I can easily query on this field value, like

> `$filter=Owner/EMail eq 'myemail@gmail.com'`

If I use `$expand=Owner&$select=Owner/EMail`, it is ok, but I cannot use Owner/Email on $filter. I just want to get items that have the same LoginName or Email with current login user.

What is the problem with **Notification1** list?
Any ways to filter in case the people field does not show up on result?

Answer (score 0):

The value does not show up since the field is set with MultiUser. By now, it does not support query on such field. We might have to write service api to fit this requirement or use more than one query to find desire results.